# .BAT don't extract the file but cmd-line do

Tags: batch-file, unzip, 7zip

I created the file extract.bat with the code:

```
@echo off

7z x "f:\Downloads\*.zip" –o"f:\Downloads"
7z x "f:\Downloads\*.rar" –o"f:\Downloads"
7z x "f:\Downloads\*.7z" –o"f:\Downloads"

pause
```

If I open the cmd and run the code:

```
7z x "f:\Downloads\*.zip" –o"f:\Downloads"
```

It works, but if I open the .BAT file, the zip isn't extracted.

Why???

Thank you!

Update: Output after run extract.bat:

```
F:\Programas>7z x "F:\Downloads\*.zip" ΓÇôo"f:\Downloads"

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 731338124 bytes (698 MiB)

Extracting archive: F:\Downloads\PromoVideo[720p].zip
--
Path = F:\Downloads\PromoVideo[720p].zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 731338124


No files to process
Everything is Ok

Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 731338124

F:\Programas>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

and output after run the command directly into cmd:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Diego>7z x "F:\Downloads\*.zip" -o"f:\Downloads"

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 731338124 bytes (698 MiB)

Extracting archive: F:\Downloads\PromoVideo[720p].zip
--
Path = F:\Downloads\PromoVideo[720p].zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 731338124

Everything is Ok

Size:       731544885
Compressed: 731338124

C:\Users\Diego>
```

As you can see, if i run the command:

```
7z x "F:\Downloads\*.zip" –o"f:\Downloads"
```

Directly into cmd it works, but it don't work if i open the .BAT file.

Any idea, pls?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you add the 7zip path to the %path% variable?

Comment: @RicardoBohner yes, i added.
it shows up some info about 7zip, but dont extract the file from bat file.
Any idea?  ty!!!

Comment: @user3790692 Comment out the `@echo off` line and post the complete output, including the `7z` output. Are both the batch file and cmd line executed at the same prompt?

Comment: Does this work `for %%a in (*.zip) do (7z x "F:\Downloads\%%~fa" -o"F:\Downloads")`

Comment: @dxiv I updated the post with the output. Thank you for help.

Comment: @Wasif_Hasan it dont work. Nothing happens. I think its because the .bat file is at folder: F:\Programas instead F:\Downloads . btw thank you for ur help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.bat` file echo'd:

> `F:\Programas>7z x "F:\Downloads\*.zip" ΓÇôo"f:\Downloads"`

`ΓÇô` in OEM [codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) is hex bytes `E2 80 93`, which represent the [en-dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) `–` in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding. But `7z` expects a plain dash `-o` switch, so it does not recognize `ΓÇôo` (or even an en-dash `–o`) as a switch.

To fix the issue, make sure to:

- use a plain `-` dash in the `.bat` file (not any other fancy character that may look like a dash);
- save the `.bat` file as plain text (not  UTF-8).

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! It fixes after I copy and paste, with out using the char in my keyboard. ^^